# How can I group by below table from Customer ID and Product Code and get them to one row?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I group by below table from Customer ID and Product Code and get them to one row as below using Python?

| **Customer ID** | **Product Code** | **Days since the last transaction** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 1 | 23 |
| A | 1 | 7 |
| A | 2 | 8 |
| A | 2 | 9 |
| A | 3 | 6 |
| B | 1 | 18 |
| B | 2 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 12 |
| C | 2 | 27 |
| C | 2 | 15 |

Need to get below table by grouping them by  Customer ID and Product Code.

| **Customer ID** | **Product Code** | **D1** | **D2** | **D3** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | 23 | 7 |
| A | 2 | 8 | 9 | N/A |
| A | 3 | 6 | N/A | N/A |
| B | 1 | 18 | N/A | N/A |
| B | 2 | 4 | N/A | N/A |
| B | 3 | 4 | 12 | N/A |
| C | 2 | 27 | 15 | N/A |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[''] = df.groupby(['Customer ID', 'Product Code']).cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index=['Customer ID', 'Product Code'], columns='')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                         Days since the last transaction
                                                       0     1    2
Customer ID Product Code
A           1                                       10.0  23.0  7.0
            2                                        8.0   9.0  NaN
            3                                        6.0   NaN  NaN
B           1                                       18.0   NaN  NaN
            2                                        4.0   NaN  NaN
            3                                        4.0  12.0  NaN
C           2                                       27.0  15.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Below python code also worked for me.

```
#keep only the needed data
grouped = df.groupby(['Customer_ID','Product Code'], as_index=False).agg({"Days since the last transaction": lambda x: x.tolist()[:3]+[x.iat[-1]]}).explode("Days since the last transaction")

#get the count for the age columns
grouped["idx"] = grouped.groupby(['Customer_ID','Product Code']).cumcount().add(1)

#pivot to get the required structure
output = grouped.pivot(["Customer_ID","Product Code"],"idx","Days since the last transaction").add_prefix("Days since the last transaction").reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

output.head()
```